# What part of my oven should be hottest, top or bottom?

Tags: temperature, everyday-life, air, heat-conduction, convection

My oven has the heating element in the bottom. So the bottom shelf is more directly exposed to it, and should be the hottest shelf.

But hot air rises, so the top shelf should have the hottest air, and should be the hottest shelf.

I don't know which logic to follow! What part of my oven should be the hottest?

Comment: Anecdotally, recipes may tell you which shelf to use. They tend to consider the top shelf the hottest.

Comment: Also:  if you don't get a satisfactory answer here you might try asking on [cooking.SE].

Comment: I've hidden a comment that should have been posted as an answer, and some replies to it.

Answer (score 2):

Oven thermometers are inexpensive. I suggest you buy a few, put them at different places in your oven, and experiment.

A more practical solution to your problem (rather than an answer to your question) would be to buy one oven thermometer, keep it on the same shelf as whatever you're baking, and trust its temperature reading instead of the temperature reported by the oven thermostat.

If I were in the oven-engineering business, I would want the temperature to be as uniform as possible throughout the volume. However, I have a habit of overengineering things. An oven manufacturer would rather sell lots of okay ovens with temperature gradients than sell a smaller number of excellently uniform ovens.

Kitchen ovens transfer heat by convection. Air is heated by the element (or the gas flame) which is located at the bottom of the oven.  Warmer tends to move upward, and cooler air moves downward to replace it. The air is what transfers heat to the food. But this means the details of the airflow are going to depend on what you have in the oven: its placement, its total heat capacity, its water content. If you have prepared a big holiday meal where you have two or three or four dishes in the oven at the same time, you have noticed that the oven goes a little different than when you just have one dish on the center rack.

The temperature distribution will depend on the mass distribution of the oven walls — the hot walls help maintain the air temperature without the cooler air needing to circulate all the way down to the element. I learned this when I thought I'd bake a potato in my low-mass toaster oven instead of the big kitchen oven. Same air temperature, but a very different ratio of total heat capacities between the hot oven and the cool food. It took *forever*.

Another experiment, cheaper than a bunch of oven thermometers, would be to bake some flatbreads at different heights, directly on the oven racks. (Pizza crusts would work, but cheese on top would break the symmetry.) At the bottom of the oven, the localized heat from the element will scorch the bottom of the bread before the top is done. As you move up, that asymmetry will be reduced, but the cooking *time* will tell you about the air temperature.